# How do I interpret the dlnm Contour plot and Overall plot in R?

Tags: r, nonlinear

I draw following figure using the `DLNM` package in **R**.

Datasheet a has variables `y` and `x1`. I assume that the continuous dependent variable `y` has gaussian distribution and that continuous independent variable `x1` has a relationship with `y` with a normal spline of $df=3$ (two knots).

I used following **R** code

```
x1.bs <- crossbasis(a$x1, lag=c(0,16), 
  argvar=list(fun="ns", knots=c(55,75), int=FALSE, cen=48), 
  arglag=list(fun="ns", df=3))
model <- glm(y~x1.bs, data=a, family=gaussian())
pred.bs <- crosspred(x1.bs, model, cumul=TRUE)
plot(pred.bs, "contour", xlim=c(40,80), 
  xlab="independent x", ylab="lag (weeks)", main="Contour graph")
plot(pred.bs, "overall", ylab="Unit", lwd = 1.5, 
  main = "Overall effect", ci.level = 0.95, 
  ci.arg = list(density = 20, col = grey(0.7)))
```

**Question 1.**
How can I interpret following Contour Figure?
[image: Countour]

For example, `x1`=75 and `lag`=6 gives `0.04`. What does 0.04 means?

**Question 2.**
How can I interpret following Overall Figure?
[image: Overall]

For example, `x1`=70 and `lag`=6 gives overall effect=0.4. What does overall effect 0.4 means?